# Modify glibc dynamic linker to check if a shared library has been loaded in another process

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries, glibc, build-error

I want to modify the glibc dynamic linker/loader so that before mapping a shared library into a process, the linker/loader checks whether the library has been loaded/in-use by any other process in the system or not. The linker/loader will perform a specific operation on the shared library code only if the library has not been used/loaded by any other process. I understand that currently the linker/loader only linearly maps the shared library and waits for demand paging to physically load the library.

I have tried to use the shell command `lsof /path/library.so` from within the dynamic linker/loader code to accomplish that. To invoke `lsof` command from within dynamic linker code, I have tried

1. `system("lsof /path/library.so")`
2. `File* fp=popen("lsof /path/library.so", "r")`

Building dynamic linker, however, gives me *"multiple definitions of x symbols"* error as I tried to include stdio.h (for `popen()`) or stdlib.h (for `system()`) header files. Can you please suggest how to resolve the glibc build error or any other better way to solve my original problem?

Addition 1: Thanks @EmployedRussian. I also explored the option that you mentioned.

> One possible answer is: store them in a file or a database. If that is your answer, then the solution becomes obvious: check if the file or a database entry exists. If it does, you don't need to do the computation again.

The main problem for both `lsof` or file/databased based solution is:  when I add a new .c file and `include <stdio.h>` in that file to do file operations (such as `FILE* fp = fopen()`), the glibc build gives me errors like this for few functions:  
                                                                                      `` '-Wl,-(' /path/glibc-2.30_build/elf/dl-allobjs.os /path/glibc-2.30_build/libc_pic.a -lgcc '-Wl,-)' -Wl,-Map,/path/glibc-2.30_build/elf/librtld.mapT /usr/bin/ld: /path/glibc-2.30_build/libc_pic.a(dl-error.os): in function `__GI__dl_signal_exception': /path/glibc_2.30_shared_library/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:91: multiple definition of `_dl_signal_exception'; /path/glibc-2.30_build/elf/dl-allobjs.os:/path/glibc_2.30_shared_library/elf/dl-error-skeleton.c:91: first defined here ``

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - What are you _really_ trying to accomplish? What is the "_specific operation on the shared library code_" you talk about?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't talk about the 'specific operation' as I believe that is not the focus of the question here. If that helps better understand the problem: after linearly mapping the code section into process memory, I read the code bytes (which physically loads the code pages) and compute some statistics about them. I just want to compute them once when the library is being physically loaded the first time. So wanted to check whether the shared library is being used by another process or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree with Ted about the XY. If you open the `.so` and either read or mmap it, you can statically dissect just about everything about it (e.g. using `libelf` or `readelf`). So, what extra "dynamic" info are you looking for (your "statistics") over and above what you get with just an mmap? What benefit do you get by forcing the pages to become resident [by looping fetching the mmap'ed area]?

Comment: And have you considered how you'd handle the case where the process loading the shared object doesn't have the privileges necessary to even know if any other process has that shared object loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Building dynamic linker, however, gives me "multiple definitions of x symbols" error

This is because the dynamic linker is *very special*, and you are very restricted in what you can do in the dynamic linker.

It is special because it must be a stand-alone program -- it can't use any other library (including `libc.so.6`) -- it is responsible for *loading* all other libraries, so naturally it can't use anything that it has yet to load.

> I just want to compute them once when the library is being physically loaded the first time.

This is *still* an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you going to *do* with the result of this computation?

One possible answer is: store them in a file or a database.

If that is your answer, then the solution becomes obvious: check if the file or a database entry exists. If it does, you don't need to do the computation again.

**Update:**

> The main problem for both lsof or file/databased based solution is: when I add a new .c file and include <stdio.h> in that file to do file operations (such as FILE* fp = fopen()), the glibc build gives me errors

This is the exact same problem: you are trying to use parts of `libc.so` which can't be used in a dynamic linker.

If you want to store the result of your computation in a file, you need to use low-level parts which *are* usable. Use `open()` and `write()` instead of `fopen()` and `fprintf()`.

Alternatively, do it from within your library or program -- since you will no longer care about how many processes have loaded the library, there is *no reason* to try to perform this computation in the loader. (There *might* be a reason, but you are not explaining it; so we are back to XY problem.)

Comment: Thanks @EmployedRussian for your reply. I edited the main post with 'Addition 1' to explain the problem I am having.

Comment: Thanks @EmplyedRussian for your answer. It works :)

Comment: @ssultana -- an etiquette note: if the answer helped you, upvote it. If it resolved your issue, accept it. That's your (only) way to reward people trying to help you.